# Join absolute paths

Tags: powershell, path

I need to join two paths, each of those can be absolute. In such a case the second path should win, if both are. But the `Join-Path` commandlet doesn't seem to produce the desired result:

```
> Join-Path 'path' 'C:\Windows'
path\C:\Windows
```

The result produced is invalid as long as the 2d path is absolute no matter what I tried, quite surprisingly for me, because I guess I'm too used to path joining facilities in other languages where this would result in `C:\Windows`.

How can I solve this? I use Powershell Core v7.1.

Comment: 'path' is not absolute. I don't see any language coming up with 'c:\windows' based on the terms 'path' and 'c:\windows' - do you have an example of this?

Comment: I don't think I understand what do you mean and what does this have to do with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that behavior in PowerShell, don't use the `Join-Path` cmdlet, because it is merely combining the `Path` parameter together with the `ChildPath` parameter (in that order) using the backslash and makes sure these backslashes aren't doubled in doing so.

The alternative that **does** do what you expect is to use .NET

```
[System.IO.Path]::Combine('path','C:\Windows')               # --> C:\Windows
[System.IO.Path]::Combine('D:\somewhere\path','C:\Windows')  # --> C:\Windows
```